# How to "dock" a Silverlight control

Tags: css, silverlight

Is there any way to "dock" a Silverlight control to the browser window? For example, I'd like to have an HTML header at the top of a page and then have the Silverlight control take up precisely the rest of the window, neatly resizing whenever the window is resized.

The default page Visual Studio creates uses styles with 100% widths and heights to make the Silverlight control take up the entire window. And I can easily modify that template to split the page by percent (say 20% HTML header and 80% Silverlight control). But what I really want is the header height to be static and the Silverlight control to take up 100% of the remaining window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution in JavaScript. First, you create this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resizeSLHost()
    {
        var docHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
        var pluginHeight = docHeight - 130;
        var slplugin = document.getElementById("silverlightControlHost");
        slplugin.style.height = pluginHeight + "px";
    }
</script>
```

Then, in your opening body tag, you say:

```
<body onload="resizeSLHost()" onresize="resizeSLHost()">
```

And you place your header div right before the Silverlight host div:

```
<div id="header" style="height:130px"></div>
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2" type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
        // the usual stuff here...
    </object>
    <iframe style='visibility:hidden;height:0;width:0;border:0px'></iframe>
</div>
```

Of course, the number you subtract from docHeight in resizeSLHost() must be equal to the height of the header div.
That worked for me in IE 7 and Firefox 3.0.4.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to still use your CSS to do this.  Just make your header DIV the size you want and then the container DIV for the Silverlight element be 100%/100%

Comment: I've tried that, but the 100% height seems to mean 100% of the containing element's height, not 100% of the containing element's height minus the header div. So the end result is a vertical scroll bar because the Silverlight control is too big by precisely the header div height.

Comment: If I misunderstood your suggestion and you're able to make this work, could you please provide a quick example?